# Generating Twillio video token with my php server

Tags: php, video, token

I'm trying to set up my own php accessToken server to grant new token for different user on my ios swift app.

I've set it up already, and can get the token key, however when the videoQuickStart app uses the token key get from my server, it will not connect to room, and even if I try to use the "token.php" from here : https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/video-quickstart-php/blob/master/token.php it still not working.

It seems like my key is not validated?

Can anyone helps?

Here's my implement of server, which is almost identical to the original one.

```
< ? php
include('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dashboard/vendor/autoload.php');

use Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken;

use Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VideoGrant;


// Required for all Twilio access tokens

$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'XXXXX';

$TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID = 'XXXX';

$TWILIO_API_KEY = 'XXXX';

$TWILIO_API_SECRET = 'XXXXX';


// An identifier for your app - can be anything you'd like

$identity = $_GET['name'];

// Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client

$token = new AccessToken(
$TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
$TWILIO_API_KEY, 
$TWILIO_API_SECRET, 
3600, 
$identity
);




$grant = new VideoGrant();

$grant->setConfigurationProfileSid($TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID);

$token->addGrant($grant);


// render token to string

echo json_encode(array(
'identity' => $identity,
'token' => $token->toJWT(),
));
?>
```

Comment: "It seems like my key is not validated" I guess talk to Twilio would be the best solution for that?

Comment: Thanks, will try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed.

It turns out I misplaced TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID and TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID.

Thanks guys